# Python output number of files in each sub directory to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to get a summary of the number of files in each subdirectory on a Linux system into an excel sheet.

The directory is generally set up: `maindir/person/task/somedata/files`.
However, the subdirectory set up varies (i.e., some of the files may not have a '`task`' directory), so I need to have python walk the file paths.

My problem is I need all subdirectory names from '`person`' on and currently my code (below) only attaches the closest directory with the file count. If anyone can help me figure this out, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
import os, sys, csv

outwriter = csv.writer(open("Subject_Task_Count.csv", 'w'))

dir_count=[]
os.chdir('./../../')
rootDir = "./" # set the directory you want to start from
for root, dirs, files in os.walk( rootDir ):
for d in dirs:
    a = str(d)
    count = 0
    for f in files:
        count+=1
    y= (a,count)
    dir_count.append(y)

for i in dir_count:
    outwriter.writerow(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't clear on your question and you may want to re-read the os.walk documentation.  `root` is the current directory being traversed.  `dirs` is the subdirectories immediately in `root`, and `files` are the files directly in `root`.  As your code is now you count the same files (from root) and record it as the number of files in each subdirectory.

This is what I came up with.  Hopefully it is close to what you want.  If not, adapt :)  It prints a directory, the number of files in the directory, and the number of files in the directory and all its subdirectories.

```
import os
import csv

# Open the csv and write headers.
with open("Subject_Task_Count.csv",'wb') as out:
    outwriter = csv.writer(out)
    outwriter.writerow(['Directory','FilesInDir','FilesIncludingSubdirs'])

    # Track total number of files in each subdirectory by absolute path
    totals = {}

    # topdown=False iterates lowest level (leaf) subdirectories first.
    # This way I can collect grand totals of files per subdirectory.
    for path,dirs,files in os.walk('.',topdown=False):
        files_in_current_directory = len(files)

        # Start with the files in the current directory and compute a
        # total for all subdirectories, which will be in the `totals`
        # dictionary already due to topdown=False.
        files_including_subdirs = files_in_current_directory
        for d in dirs:
            fullpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path,d))

            # On my Windows system, Junctions weren't included in os.walk,
            # but would show up in the subdirectory list.  this try skips
            # them because they won't be in the totals dictionary.
            try:
                files_including_subdirs += totals[fullpath]
            except KeyError as e:
                print 'KeyError: {} may be symlink/junction'.format(e)

        totals[os.path.abspath(path)] = files_including_subdirs
        outwriter.writerow([path,files_in_current_directory,files_including_subdirs])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help,this one worked out perfectly, sorry I didn't have a chance to check it until today.

Answer (score 4):

You should try something along the lines of:

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk( rootDir ) :
    print root, len(files)
```

which prints subdirectories and the number of files.